# When exactly is the destructor called in C++

Tags: c++

Consider following code

```
int i;

class A
{
public:
   ~A()
   {
       i=10;
   }
};

int foo()
{
   i=3;
   A ob;
   return i;
}

int main()
{
   cout << foo() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Since `i` is global, I thought the output of this program should be `10`. `ob`, when it goes out of scope will call the destructor which should set value of `i` to `10`.

Comment: The `}` brace generates a lot of code in C++ :)

Comment: @HansPassant Never trust a language where the "end block" keyword is itself Turing complete. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Local variables go out of scope, and their destructors are executed, *after* the function returns. Which means that by the time `~A()` runs, the return value is already `3`. In contrast, if you did this...

```
int foo()
{
   {
      i=3;
      A ob;
   }
   return i;
}
```

...`ob` would go out of scope and die before the return statement, and the result would be 10.

Extra scopes are often used this way with RAII-active types like `scoped_lock`, to go into some particular side-effect-ful state for only part of a function.

Answer (score 8):

```
int foo()
{
   i=3;
   A ob;
   return i;
} // <- ~A() is called here
```

`~A()` is called at the end of the function `foo()`, when `ob` goes out of scope. This is after the return value is calculated (i.e. a copy of `i`, with the value of `3` at that time).

In order for `i` to be set to `10` before the function exits, you would need to force `ob` to go "out of scope earlier". The simplest is to add an additional scope around `A ob`.

```
int foo()
{
   i=3;
   {
     A ob;
   } // <- ~A() is called here and sets i to 10
   return i;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`ob` goes out of scope after the return is executed. Consider what would happen if `ob` was involved in the evaluation of the return expression and it would have gone out of scope before the return.

Answer (score 4):

`ob` doesn't go out of scope until the end of the scope, i.e. at the `}` that occurs after the `return` statement. That's when the destructor gets called, but by then `i` has already been evaluated so its old value is returned.

Answer (score 3):

The `~A()` is called when `ob` goes out of scope.
Assembly proof:

```
<__Z3foov>:
    push   %ebp
    mov    %esp,%ebp
    push   %ebx
    sub    $0x10,%esp
    movl   $0x3,0x407020        /* <-- setting i to 3 */
    mov    0x407020,%ebx        /* <-- loading i to %ebx */
    lea    -0x5(%ebp),%eax
    mov    %eax,%ecx
    call   403860 <__ZN1AD1Ev>  /* <-- calling destructor */
    mov    %ebx,%eax            /* <-- returnign already calculated i from %ebx */
    add    $0x10,%esp
    pop    %ebx
    pop    %ebp
    ret  

<__ZN1AD1Ev>:               /* <-- the destructor */
    push   %ebp
    mov    %esp,%ebp
    sub    $0x4,%esp
    mov    %ecx,-0x4(%ebp)
    movl   $0xa,0x407020    /* <-- set i to 10 */
    leave  
    ret
```

As you can see, the destructor is called after the return value is put to `%ebx`, which is again moved to `%eax` when destructor is done. For your future questions about behavior of C++ code, disassembly is your best friend.